# Function template in non-template class

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm sure that it is possible but I just can't do it, which is: How can I define function template inside non-template class? I tryied something like this:

```
class Stack_T
{
    private:
        void* _my_area;
        static const int _num_of_objects = 10;

    public:
        // Allocates space for objects added to stack
        explicit Stack_T(size_t);
        virtual ~Stack_T(void);

        // Puts object onto stack
        template<class T>
        void put(const T&);

        // Gets last added object to the stack
        template<class T>
        T& get()const;

        // Removes last added object from the stack
        template<class T>
        void remove(const T&);
};

template<class T> //SOMETHING WRONG WITH THIS DEFINITION
void Stack_T::put<T>(const T& obj)
{
}
```

but it doesn't work. I'm getting this err msg:

'Error  1   error C2768: 'Stack_T::put' : illegal use of explicit template arguments'
Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't put the `<T>` after the function name. This should work:

```
template<class T>
void Stack_T::put(const T& obj)
{
}
```

---

This still won't work if the function definition is not in the header file. To solve this, use one of:

- Put the function definition in the header file, inside the class.
- Put the function definition in the header file after the class (like in your example code).
- Use explicit template instanciation in the header file. This has serious limitations though (you have to know all possible values of T in advance).

Comment: I tryied this but I'm getting an error:

'Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Stack_T::put<int>(int const &)" (??$put@H@Stack_T@@QAEXABH@Z) referenced in function _wmain Stack_of_Objects.obj
'

Comment: template<class T>
void Stack_T<T>::put(const T& obj)
{
}

Comment: @Harry No, that won't work. `Stack_T` is not a template.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This really helped me. Nevertheless, how would I "use explicit template instanciation" ? What does that virtually mean ?