# How do I make a non-templated manager accept templated objects?

Tags: c++, templates

I've made a generic property template. Each of the properties is only one value, for example float, int, string, etc. And when the property is instantiated, it attempts to register itself with the property manager singleton. However, I can't figure out how to make the PropertyManager::AddProperty() method take the property. It keeps erroring out with a message stating that the Property needs a typename. How is this normally done?

```
template <typename T> class Property
{
public:
    Property(T value)
    { 
        mID = ThePropertyManager->AddProperty( Property* p ); 
    } 
        T mValue;
    ULONG mID;
}
```

Comment: What operations does the `PropertyManager` need to access from the `Property`? -- The question is calling out *type erasure* but the way to do it can depend on what you need to do with the `Property`

Comment: getting managers to accept anything can be difficult

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    mID = ThePropertyManager->AddProperty( Property* p );
```

is invalid syntax in two ways, it needs to be

```
    mID = ThePropertyManager->AddProperty(this);
```

It's hard to be certain without seeing the rest of your code, but as long as `AddProperty` is itself templated then this should work.

Also you presumably want to initialize `mValue` in the constructor, i.e.

```
Property(T value) : mValue(value)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: The AddProperty function is a member function. Can I still make it templated without making the entire PropertyManager templated?

Comment: @user1527741 Sure.  You have to be careful with the syntax, and what goes in the `.cpp` vs `.h` files, but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799445/function-template-in-non-template-class).

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyManager class can have a template member function that takes various instantiations of Property:

```
class PropertyManager
{
public:
    template <class TY> ID AddProperty(Property<Ty>&);
};
```

Note also that the sample code is incorrect:

```
mID = ThePropertyManager->AddProperty( Property* p );
```

should be something like:

```
mID = ThePropertyManager->AddProperty(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have `Property` inherit from an abstract base class, say `AbstractProperty` that does NOT have a templated type, then have `PropertyManager` accept the `AbstractProperty` arguments.  This would also support multiple `Property` templated classes if you were using `Property` with ints, floats, etc all together.

Though it does sound like you're going down the path of needing a templated Property Manager.

Comment: Uhoh, what are the implications of having a templated Property Manager? Don't I end up with more than one? I only want a single property manager, so I'd like to avoid that at all costs. But going back to your other suggestion, use a Abstract Property class, I like that idea. I'm going to try that out.

Comment: Without knowing what the "Property Manager" is supposed to do, it's really not possible to give a useful answer. An abstract base class may be the solution, but that depends on what the problem is.

Comment: >Uhoh, what are the implications of having a templated Property >Manager? Don't I end up with more than one?

Maybe, it would get a little convoluted to avoid having more than one.

Comment: MartyE! You gave me the right answer! It works now :) I would upvote you, but it says I need more than 15 points to do it. Anyway, thanks a bunch, dude!

Comment: @user1527741  You can always accept the answer and it will give it the green check